# Label filtering

Tags: javascript

I want to filter the label to search for "1125" if it does not exist it will display an alert box. So here is my code:

```
if (var id = $('mobilelabel_2:contains("1125")').attr('for');)
{
    alert ("works");
}
else
{
    alert ("try again");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried checking for syntax errors?

Comment: And what's your HTML? And there's no `mobilelabel_2` element, did you mean to use a class? Or an `id`?

Comment: Semicolons are used for code line ends.

Comment: hello @user3058905, welcome on SO. It would be easier for people to provide help if you give (as little as possible) context. E.g. in this case the related bit of HTML, or the console output to see errors, as pointed out by others before me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `.` or `#` character to indicate an `id` or `class` selector:

```
  if ($('#mobilelabel_2:contains("1125")').length > 0)
  {
      alert ("works");
  }else{
      alert ("try again");
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<label id="mobilelabel_2">Test 1125</label>
```

Also notice the revised syntax for the if conditional.  It is unnecessary to select the `for` attribute and store it into a variable.  Instead you can check for the existence of the element containing `1125` using the length property.

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/8R98b/

Comment: Your code works but it does not seem like the app will recognize the label.. only getting "try again"

Comment: Post the html for the label

Comment: I feel stupid.. haha, was using the name instead of the id -.-

<!-- mobilelabel_2 -->
                <div name="mobilelabel_2" id="Scan_mobilelabel_2" dsid="mobilelabel_2" data-role="appery_label"
                class='mobilelabel_2 Scan_mobilelabel_2 '>

Comment: Works now! Thanks mate! <3

Answer (score 0):

Tip, before posting code here always run your code through either [jshint](http://jshint.com) or [jslint](http://jslint.com)

Running through jshint your code gets the following 11 warnings!

```
1   Expected an identifier and instead saw 'var'.
1   Expected ')' to match '(' from line 1 and instead saw 'id'.
1   Expected an identifier and instead saw '='.
1   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
1   Missing semicolon.
1   Expected an identifier and instead saw ')'.
1   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
1   Missing semicolon.
5   Expected an identifier and instead saw 'else'.
5   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
5   Missing semicolon
```

I think you may be trying to write:

```
if ($('#mobilelabel_2:contains("1125")').length > 0)//ele with id mobilelabel_2 contains text 1125
{
    alert ("works");
}
else
{
    alert ("try again");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed your code, I think JQuery..?

```
if (var id = $("#mobilelabel_2:contains('1125')").attr('for')
{
    alert ("works");
}
else
{
    alert ("try again");
}
```